# Why does Heroku recommend using pg:upgrade insted of pg:copy?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

We are planning to upgrade our Postgres database on Heroku.

In order to prepare for the migration I've read the [upgrading guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases) by Heroku.
In the beginning they present two possible ways to run the upgrade:

`pg:upgrade`
`pg:copy`

Then they write under the `pg:upgrade` method that

> "this method is recommended [...]".

But unfortunately they lack an explanation there.

It seems that `pg:copy` is faster for databases with less than `10 GB` in size and it also works for hobby plans and the overall process seems to be less complicated.

So why is it still better to use `pg:upgrade` ?